# can we give specific IP address and port number to launch javaFx applicaton

Tags: javafx

My desktop is configured with 2 NIC (2 IP addresses), and when I launched the javaFx application, it is opened with one specific IP address among 2 available IP addresses.

Could you please help me, how the javaFx picks the IP address and port number when we launch the application?

Can we give specific IP address and port number to launch javaFx application ?

Thanks in advance, any kind of help is appreciated.

**Note:** In my case, main java process is running on a linux server, the javaFx standalone app is launched through a windows desktop. Here one desktop IP is unreachable from the server and when i try to run code from the server, it is using the unreachable IP to launch it in desktop. So, we are unable to make any RMI calls from the server to desktop as it is unreachable. hence we are failing to send data to the app. We don't have option to make it reachable from the server. so i am looking to use other reachable IP address to launch the app

Comment: And where is the code? In general, the choice of the IP address and port to be listened to is a configuration option. In most cases, the IP address is skipped (or set to 0.0.0.0) so the app listens to all available addresses.

Comment: Thanks mcwolf, In my case, main java process is running on a linux server, the javaFx standalone app is launched through a windows desktop. Here one desktop IP is unreachable from the server and when i try to run code from the server, it is using the unreachable IP to launch it in desktop. So, we are unable to make any RMI calls from the server to desktop as it is unreachable. hence we are failing to send data to the app. We don't have option to make it reachable from the server. so i am looking to use other reachable IP address to launch the app.beg pardon,code is huge so i can't post it here

Comment: Something I do not like the play. Communication in client-server architecture applications is always done at the initiative of customers. So the server has a channel to answer. In your case, you obviously have communication at the initiative of the server (push event?). In this case, customers must register (tell which port and which IP address they are listening to). The other option is to use broadcast or multicast messages. This solution is very good but only applicable to private networks (these packages are not routed by default).

Comment: Thanks mcwolf, you understood well, In server-client model, we are trying to push event from server to client. But here the client is JavaFx app which is launched in desktop. and we are trying to send the data to the app from server using RMI call. But here app is launching with unexpected IP address in the desktop. So, i want the app to use other IP address available for the desktop. Do we have any configuration settings, that app uses the given one(one of available 2 addresses)?  based on which parameter app choose the IP address of the desktop. as it is public n/w can't use broadcast.

Comment: In this situation, the FX application is a server to which the server is attached to make the notification. Try setting the desired IP address (or 0.0.0.0) to java.rmi.server.hostname.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html